# According to google my desktop site is not mobile friendly

Tags: codeigniter, redirect, google-search-console, googlebot

I have desktop view(test.com) and mobile view(m.test.com) site.
I am redirecting to mobile view through codeigniter constructor .

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('user_agent');

    if ($this->agent->is_browser())
    {
        if($this->agent->mobile()){
            $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            header('Location: http://m.test.com'.$url); 
        }
    }
}
```

and it was working fine.
also included annotations in my site main layout file.

IN desktop link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="http://m.test.com/"

IN mobile link rel="canonical" href="http://www.test.com/"

but google still showing that my site is not mobile friendly.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your site as it currently is, it is *not* mobile friendly. It seems to miss several of the following criteria:

> A page is eligible for the “mobile-friendly” label if it meets the following criteria as detected by Googlebot:
> Avoids software that is not common on mobile devices, like Flash
> Uses text that is readable without zooming
> Sizes content to the screen so users don't have to scroll horizontally or zoom
> Places links far enough apart so that the correct one can be easily tapped

Source:
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2014/11/helping-users-find-mobile-friendly-pages.html

I'v tried it on IE on my Noke phone. It just looks like a desktop site.

Comment: I have crossed checked twice the site according to their mobile friendly creteria.

Comment: When i have looked at your mobile site (m.test.com), i see only a desktop site. No fluid layout. No resizing of text according to screen size or density. Viewed in mobile Internet Explorer on a small screen, its a desktop site. Tiny text and I have to zoom in.

Are you sure the mobile site link that I am seeing (by accessing m.test.com), is the one you intend to be seen as a 'mobile friendly' site?

Comment: my friend i have used m.test.com just for an example my site domain is different.

Comment: Ok-
1) can you edit your question to make that clear, because that wasn't at all clear
2) Without actually seeing your site, how are we meant to work out why it wasn't judged mobile friendly? Just redirecting to a mobile page is apparently not sufficient for googlebot. Its judging your site on a set of mobile friendly criteria. If we can't see your site, we can't guess what the problem might be.

Comment: Yeh i understand that thing but client is not allowing that.
Content wider than screen
Links too close together

Comment: this is what i get  from the test.

Comment: and screen the show is my desktop site home not the mobile site.

Comment: redirection is working now i have never faced any redirection issue and i have also provided the annotations accordingly.